# How to enable force_basic_auth in Ansible Galaxy when installing roles?

Tags: ansible, artifactory, basic-authentication, ansible-galaxy

I have Ansible roles packed and uploaded in JFrog Artifactory.
Username and password or username and identity token (passed as password) need to be provided to download files.
When I download any files from Artifactory, I need to set `force_basic_auth: true` in the module `ansible.builtin.get_url` (`username` and `password` are also provided), otherwise Artifactory returns 404 error.

My problem is when I try to install the above mentioned role with `ansible-galaxy`, I can specify the credentials as part of the URL, but cannot set `force_basic_auth: true`.

My command is:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

requirements.yml:

```
- src: https://<username>:<password>@artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/repo/namespace/component/version/component-version.tar.gz
  name: component
```

How could I install the role hosted in Artifactory?

I edited `ansible/module_utils/urls.py` to set `force_basic_auth=True` before making the request. That made the installation work.

Download with cUrl also works using the same URL.

```
curl https://<username>:<password>@artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/repo/namespace/component/version/component-version.tar.gz -o role.tar.gz
```

Comment: What repo type are you using to store the role ? Is it generic one ?

Comment: @ALex_hha, currently it is in a Maven repo, so it can be together with the Maven artifacts. Other option would be the generic repo type.